# Facebook comments plugin - text is lost after login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-comments

When I an adding a comment on Facebook comments plugin on logout state, a "Log In to Post" button appears.

[image]

I press it and log in, the webview is reloading in a logged in state and the text is lost.

[image]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: This should be working correctly. Which browser/OS are you using? Do you have an example page where you have implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have code posted. I only can remind you `String` and `Array` are "pass by value"

Answer (score 0):

What you can do for a basic and quick fix is to use the NSUserDefaults to save on the tapping of the "Log into Post" and then reload that string back when the user has logged in.

The reason the text is being lost is, I am assuming here, that there is no function for caching or storing that string and it just reloads the source code with the user's token but not any text that was typed prior to that.

So in conclusion, try saving the string when that button is pressed. Then reload the text and change the value of the input text programmatically. Does that make sense? I am often confusing when I try to explain things.